# ZF2 - Can I load modules from `development.config.php` first?

Tags: module, configuration, zend-framework2, loading

I want to load [ghislainf/zf2-whoops](https://github.com/ghislainf/zf2-whoops) only on development environments, but it says I have to load it first (meaning in `application.config.php`).

Is there a way to load `development.config.php` modules first?

**UPDATE:**

I'm loading the env variables using [abacaphiliac/zend-phpdotenv](https://github.com/abacaphiliac/zend-phpdotenv), meaning the env variables are not loaded yet by the time the `application.config.php` is being processed.  For this reason I can't use dynamic loading based on environment.  That's the reason I was looking to load development modules first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily setup different configuration files for different environments. So one configuration for **development** and a different one for **production**.

This is very well described in the [Zend Framework documentation chapter called **Advanced Configuration Tricks**](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html) and more specifically [here in **Environment-specific system configuration**](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-system-configuration):

The trick they use is to set the `APP_ENV` global variable and set it to either `production` or `development`.

```
<?php
$env = getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'production';

// Use the $env value to determine which modules to load
$modules = array(
    'Application',
);
if ($env == 'development') {
    $modules[] = 'ZendDeveloperTools';
}
```

When using this solution you can in each config load the modules that you need in the order that you need them.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco did you read the documentation that I referred to in my answer? You can set the environmental variables in your htaccess file.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that. We're following [12factor](https://12factor.net/) so we're loading env variables using dotenv. However, I think we might as well use dotenv directly rather than the zf2 module for it.

Comment: I think it is good practice to load environmental variables on server and not on application level.